# How to apply qss to a QCalendarWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qtstylesheets, qcalendarwidget

Good evening I am trying to generate a calendar like the one in the image:

[image]

So far what I have achieved with the QSS is this:

[image]

And this is the QSS that I have used

```
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView
{ 
selection-background-color: #042944; 
selection-color: white;
selection-border:10px solid red;

}
QCalendarWidget QWidget 
{
  color:grey;
}
QCalendarWidget QTableView{
border-width:0px;
background-color:lightgrey;
}
```

I still need to change the color of the days (Sunday and Saturday), and that when selecting a day the edge is round.

this is what I tried:

```
QCalendarWidget{
   color:grey;
}

QCalendarWidget QTableView::item:selected{
   border-radius:30px;

}
```

but it does not work I hope you can help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not everything can be done with Qt Style Sheet, in fact it is very limited, in this case to change the color of the weekends you must use `setWeekdayTextFormat()` and to change the shape of the selected day you should use `paintCell()`.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

QSS = '''
QCalendarWidget QAbstractItemView
{ 
    selection-background-color: #042944; 
    selection-color: white;
}
QCalendarWidget QWidget 
{
  color:grey;
}
QCalendarWidget QTableView
{
    border-width:0px;
    background-color:lightgrey;
}
'''

class CalendarWidget(QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(CalendarWidget, self).__init__(parent,
            verticalHeaderFormat=QtWidgets.QCalendarWidget.NoVerticalHeader,
            gridVisible=False)

        for d in (QtCore.Qt.Saturday, QtCore.Qt.Sunday,):
            fmt = self.weekdayTextFormat(d)
            fmt.setForeground(QtCore.Qt.darkGray)
            self.setWeekdayTextFormat(d, fmt)

    def paintCell(self, painter, rect, date):
        if date == self.selectedDate():
            painter.save()
            painter.fillRect(rect, QtGui.QColor("#D3D3D3"))
            painter.setPen(QtCore.Qt.NoPen)
            painter.setBrush(QtGui.QColor("#33B5E5"))
            r = QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(), min(rect.width(), rect.height())*QtCore.QSize(1, 1))
            r.moveCenter(rect.center())
            painter.drawEllipse(r)
            painter.setPen(QtGui.QPen(QtGui.QColor("gray")))
            painter.drawText(rect, QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, str(date.day()))
            painter.restore()
        else:
            super(CalendarWidget, self).paintCell(painter, rect, date)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet(QSS)
    w = CalendarWidget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]